# Direct sum and short exact sequence, as well as, tensor product and what?

Tags: category-theory, exact-sequence, abelian-categories, monoidal-categories, additive-categories

In an abelian category, the notion of direct sum is generalized by the notion of short exact sequence (see [split exact sequence](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/split+exact+sequence)).

**Question**: In a monoidal category, can the notion of tensor product be generalized as well?

Comment: in which sense do you think short exact sequences generalize the direct sum?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz I imagine it is because when a short exact sequence is split, it is a direct sum/product. But I don't see why there would be something similar for tensor products, which can be pretty much anything.